# componentsJoinedByString with AttributedStrings causes NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting the following error while joining a array of attributed strings.

```
2014-12-14 12:57:22.280 Matchismo[57752:60b] -[NSConcreteAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e81e20
2014-12-14 12:57:22.322 Matchismo[57752:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteAttributedString _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e81e20'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017fa1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015798e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01897243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x017ea50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x017ea0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0177e4e6 CFStringAppend + 566
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x017ebf04 -[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:] + 532
    7   Matchismo                           0x00004d59 -[CardGameViewController updateTextLabel] + 345
    8   Matchismo                           0x00005334 -[CardGameViewController updateUI] + 1396
    9   Matchismo                           0x00004bdd -[CardGameViewController touchCard:] + 253
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0158b880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    11  UIKit                               0x0023b3b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    12  UIKit                               0x0023b345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    13  UIKit                               0x0033cbd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    14  UIKit                               0x0033cfc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    15  UIKit                               0x0033c243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    16  UIKit                               0x0027addd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    17  UIKit                               0x0027b9d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    18  UIKit                               0x0024d5f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    19  UIKit                               0x00237353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0178377f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0178310b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x017a01ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0179f9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0179f7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x037ee5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x037ee42b GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x00239f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    28  Matchismo                           0x00008d5d main + 141
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e41701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is my code:

```
self.textLabel.text = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

I understand that the attributed strings that have shading and what not cannot be stored in a NSString. What should be the correct code.

Attaching a screenshot of what kind of data the NSAttributed strings hold. They hold the circles/squares/triangles that you see in the image.

[image: Image of the data in the attributed strings.]

Comment: Why not append your attributed strings into a new attribute string?

Comment: Hi, your problem is in other place. [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]. "Work fine with attributedString, well It exist is a text wiht the string and the attributes dict." But It doesn't launch an exception.

Comment: Have you tried displaying (`NSLog`) or examining in the debugger the contents of your `myArray`? The occurrence of `encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString` in the error messages suggests your `NSAttributedStrings` are not what you think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append new string inside attributed string you can directly use [appendAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/appendAttributedString:) method. But it will always add at the end of attributed string.

If your requirement is to add in the middle of your attributed string and you want to add "," in each word of your attributed string with the shading attributes as well. So in this case you need to first convert your attributed string into string and then you need to store your words in array and then you need to iterate the words from array and convert that string into attributed string with your attributes and then use `appendAttributedString` with ",". Like that you can implement the same.